# read the output of nvprof in CUDA

Tags: cuda, profiler

I am running my program using nvprof to get profile information using the command:

```
nvprof -o profileOutput -s ./exe args
```

I wanted information about warp divergence, coalesced read/write, occupancy etc. But when I open the file profileOutput, its in some other format altogether and have weird symbols like @^@^.....

I am opening the file in vim. What is the correct way to see profile information of a CUDA program. Please help.

Comment: There is a [user's guide for the profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html).  Click on [nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview).   The normal [output file](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#output) is not human readable, but you can output to excel style CSV if you like.  [nvvp the visual profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#visual-profiler), is a better option if you have an X session available.

Comment: From the user guide Robert mentioned: For each profiling mode, option --output-profile can be used to generate a result file. This file is not human-readable, but can be imported to nvprof using the option --import-profile, or into the Visual Profiler.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `-s` because it is the default situation by itself.

`-o` specifies the output file which can be imported later or open by Nvidia visual profiler, which is not human readable.

If you need to compute occupancy you can use this [occupancy calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) provided by Nvidia. There's an [article](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/368105/cuda-occupancy-calculator-helps-pick-optimal-thread-block-size/) about it.

If you need to trace branches you can use profiling in trace mode and trace branches.

Answer (score 5):

You can open your output file in Nvidia Visual Profiler (usually included in CUDA SDK).

There's also one more possibility to produce human-readable files: you can specify `--log-file human-readable-output.log` option for `nvprof` (of course `human-readable-output.log` is your output file name).
You can enable some other `nvprof` options for your log output:

- `--print-gpu-trace` for GPU trace;
- `--events` for collecting events (for example branch, number of launched warps etc.);
- `--metrics` for some custom metrics (like shared load transactions, dram utilization etc - full list of metrics you can view by typing `nvprof --query-metrics` in your command line).

Full list of options you can find in [NVIDIA nvprof documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview).